# Javascript onclick to clear dropdown fields works only once per dropdown field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I've been looking at all the related questions/answers on StackOverflow, but have not found a solution specific to my situation.

I have the following HTML:

```
<select name="search_month" onclick="javascript: $('#categories').val(null);" id="months">
  <option value="">----------------</option>
  ...                                                               
</select>
<select name="search_category" onclick="javascript: $('#months').val(null);" id="categories">
  <option value="">----------------</option>
  ...                                                               
</select>
```

If I click the "search_month" dropdown, "search_category" clears just fine and vice versa. But it only works once per dropdown.

So now, let's say I made a selection for "search_month", changed my mind and made a selection for "search_category", then changed my mind... AGAIN... and decided to search by month instead (using "search_month"), when I click on a selection in the "search_month" dropdown, the javascript doesn't clear out the "search_category" dropdown.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: The code you have provided works in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w6E88/1/

Comment: BTW - You NEVER need "javascript:" in an event. What else would it be?

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - Your fiddle code didn't work for me. Maybe it's a browser thing? I'm on Chrome/Mac.

Comment: @Diodeus - Removing Javascript didn't make a difference.

Comment: That's because specifying it in the first place is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say why the onclick action wasn't firing a second time on each dropdown, but based a few responses, I removed "javascript:" from the event and I was able to change the use of "onclick" to "onchange", which made the clearing of the dropdown boxes work as expected. So my new code is as follows:

```
<select name="search_month" onchange="$('#categories').val(null);" id="months">
  <option value="">----------------</option>
  ...                                                               
</select>
<select name="search_category" onchange="$('#months').val(null);" id="categories">
  <option value="">----------------</option>
  ...                                                               
</select>
```

This is what worked for me in Chrome/Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent inline javascript :/ use a setup like this: http://jsfiddle.net/w6E88/2/

```
$("#month, #categories").change(function() {
    //do your logic here
    //retrieve value with $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value')
    //reset with $(this).value... or $("#month").val..
});
```